# how do i get rows that are equal to 1 from the database with a query?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to store the number of rows in `$rowsot` that are equal to `1`.

But my query is not working, can somebody see why `$query` is not working.

It works if i just do :

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1");
```

But this one doesn't.

```html
  $one = 1;
  $connectie = verbinddatabase();    
   $query = $connectie->prepare("
                SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE inBehandeling = '$one'");
$query->execute();
$query->store_result();
$rowsot = $query->num_rows;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use PDO and prepared statements to bind your value. Also you do not need the `'`

**PDO:**

```
$one = 1;
$connectie = verbinddatabase();    
$query = $connectie->prepare("SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE inBehandeling = :one");
$query->bindParam(':one', $one, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
$rowsot = $query->rowCount();
```

**mysqli:**

```
$one = 1;
$connectie = verbinddatabase();    
$query = $connectie->prepare("SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE inBehandeling = ?");
$query->bind_param('s', $one);
$query->execute();
$query->store_result();
$rowsot = $query->num_rows;
```

Comment: I agree that parameterized values are better, but looking at his example, it should work as well. You still _can_ concatenate your query (even if it is discouraged) and use `'` around integers, so I don't think this is a solution to the actual problem?

Comment: mysqli method worked for me, thank you but i figured out that i forgot to echo  after i changed the code with bind_param